# How can I set amount value in address(this).balance

Tags: solidity, remix, address.transfer, smart-contract, msg.sender

Like i want to Insert the value that how much ethers are transfer from my smart contract.

I tried this second day but it's not working so i'm looking for solution any help is highly appriciated

here is my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Bank{
    // Implement remaining timestamp for fd,blocklist,validations(minimum amount)
    // 
    address private owner;
    constructor() {
        owner=msg.sender;
    }
    mapping(address=>uint256)  accounts;
    mapping(address=>bool) public CheckAccount;
    mapping(address=>uint256) public fdAmount;
    mapping(address=>bool)  blockedAcc;
    uint fees=0.00005 ether;
    uint feesColl=0;

    
    function createAcc() public  {
        require(CheckAccount[msg.sender]==false,"Account Aleready Created Succefully");
        require(blockedAcc[msg.sender]==false,"You are blocked by the Owner");
        accounts[msg.sender]=msg.sender.balance;
        CheckAccount[msg.sender]=true;

    }

    function createFD() public payable {
        require(blockedAcc[msg.sender]==false,"You are blocked by the Owner");
        require(CheckAccount[msg.sender],"Create Account First");
        payable(address(this)).transfer(msg.value);
        payable(address(this)).transfer(fees);
        // _to.transfer(msg.value);
        // _to.transfer(fees);
        fdAmount[msg.sender]+=msg.value / 1 ether;
    }

    function getBalance(address _address) public view returns(uint256){
        require(blockedAcc[msg.sender]==false,"You are blocked by the Owner");
        // require(!accounts[msg.sender])
        return _address.balance / 1 ether ;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
    
    function getContractBal() public view returns(uint){
        require(blockedAcc[msg.sender]==false,"You are blocked by the Owner");
        return address(this).balance / 1 ether;

    }

    function WithdrawFD() public payable {
        require(blockedAcc[msg.sender]==false,"You are blocked by the Owner");
        //  _to.transfer(msg.value);
        // .call.value(address(this).balance)()
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
        fdAmount[msg.sender]-=msg.value / 1 ether;
    }

    function CloseAcc() public{
        require(CheckAccount[msg.sender]==true,"Account Not Exist,Create Account First");
        require(blockedAcc[msg.sender]==false,"You are blocked by the Owner");
        CheckAccount[msg.sender]=false;
        delete accounts[msg.sender];

    }
// If after created the account user marked as blacklisted then account should be closed
    function BlockUsr(address _add) public {
        CloseAcc();
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Only Owner Has the Permission");
        blockedAcc[_add]=true;

    }
     function UnBlockUsr(address _add) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Only Owner Has the Permission");
        
        blockedAcc[_add]=false;

    }


}
```

The problem is with withdraw function when i call the function the all amount is withdrawn from smart contract how want to specify the amount like msg.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add 1 more param in you withdraw function :

```
function WithdrawFD(unit amount) public payable {
    require(blockedAcc[msg.sender]==false,"You are blocked by the Owner");
    //  _to.transfer(msg.value);
    // .call.value(address(this).balance)()
    require(amount >= address(this).balance);
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    fdAmount[msg.sender]-=msg.value / 1 ether;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it